# How to get URLs to line-break within \todo{} comments?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, urls, todonotes

I am searching for a way to allow URLs to line-break at any character within a marginal comment created by the package `luatodonotes`. I installed the `xurl` package, which is one of the options for allowing URLs to break at any character within text.

The `xurl` package works for me within text but not within `\todo{}` notes. The `\todo{}` command is a moving argument, so using `\url{}` within it causes an error. Prefacing `\url{}` with \protect makes the URL render, but it still does not break as desired.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Minimal example and screenshot below.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{luatodonotes}%

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. %
\todo{this todo note has just plain text}%
%
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. %
\todo{this todo note contains a long URL using the texttt command. It renders fine but does not break: \texttt{http://www.blahblah.com/blah/blah/and-more/and-more/and-more.html}}%
%
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Here is a really long URL in the text block using the \textbackslash url command. It renders and breaks properly (well, almost): \url{http://www.blahblah.com/blah/blah/and-more/and-more/blah/blah/and-more/and-moreblah/blah/and-more/and-more-and-more.html} %
%
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.%
\todo{this todo note contains a long URL using \textbackslash protect\textbackslash url. It renders but does not break: \protect\url{http://www.blahblah.com/blah/blah/and-more/and-more/and-more.html}}%

\end{document}
```

[image: The results]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it can work with luatodonotes. If you look closely you will see that it not only prevents url to break but also hyphenation. It simply stores everything in a hbox and then breaks it into lines. With todonotes it works:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{todonotes}%
\urldef\myurl\url{http://www.blahblah.com/blah/blah/and-more/and-more/and-more.html}
\begin{document}
\listoftodos

\bigskip
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.%
\todo{this todo note contains a long URL using \textbackslash urldef. \myurl}%

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.%
\todo{this todo note contains a long URL using \textbackslash protect. \protect\url{http://www.blahblah.com/blah/blah/and-more/and-more/and-more.html}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]